# Troubleshooting an infinite redirect in a web application

Tags: redirect

I have a web application that is trying to redirect in a loop, and Firefox is telling me that it is stopping because the request will never complete. Is there a good way (in Firefox) to see what URL is being requested in this never-ending loop? The address doesn't seem to appear in the address bar. Are there any addons that can help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is an ever-popular choice.  There is a console window that will show you all the various requests that your browser is making.

I'm also a fan of [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) which gives you a separate window that shows all the headers and request results.  If your browser is making a lot of requests, you'll get a long log of them.

For the situation you describe, I'd probably go with LiveHTTPHeaders, as it logs all requests across all pages.  Firebug is better on a per-page basis, and is more useful for checking out Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Fiddler. It should show all http requests.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, all you need is the tamper data plugin:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966